# Bootstrap multiselect issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to add bootstrap multi select in http://teddyslist.com/dev/index.php. I have added multi select in the second drop down only. Previously bootstrap select was there. After adding multi select, the design has been broken.

The default label "--Select State--" is not showing now. Currently it is showing "Nothing Selected". How to change it?

The checkbox is also showing beside "--Select State--". How to delete it from here?

My code is something like below.

JQUERY in header :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#state').multiselect();
});
```

HTML :

```
<select name="state" id="state" multiple>
     <option value="">-- Select State --</option>
     <option value="1">111</option>
     <option value="2">222</option>
     <option value="3">333</option>
</select>
```

I have included bootstrap-multiselect.js and bootstrap-multiselect.css.

Can anyone please help me? Please excuse if I ask any silly question.

Answer (score 0):

change as the **multiple="multiple"** in html

```
<select name="state" id="state" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="">-- Select State --</option>
     <option value="1">111</option>
     <option value="2">222</option>
     <option value="3">333</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello codeParane,

Thanks for your reply. I have changed. But no change.